# browser doesnt display styles on page in docker nginx react

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I try docker. I write configuration for compose, and separate dockerfiles.
All services work good, but my frontend app doesnt display styles, console not have errors, style css load success. I dont have idea what is it

Dockerfile for nginx and react

```
FROM node:16.13.1 as build

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./client .

RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/client
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf, i think trouble here, but what exactly i dont know

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http{
    server{
        listen 80;

        location / {
                root /var/www/client;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
        }


        location /api {
            rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://deliverycx_backend:5000;
        }
    }
}
```

and docker compose

```
version: "3.9"
networks:
    mongodb_net:
        driver: bridge
services:
    deliverycx_client:
        container_name: deliverycx_client
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.webserver
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        networks:
          - mongodb_net
    deliverycx_backend:
        container_name: deliverycx_backend
        env_file:
            - ./server/.production.env
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - mongodb
        build:
            context: ./server
        networks:
          - mongodb_net
        links:
            - redis
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    redis:
        image: redis
        command:
            - "redis-server"
            - "--loglevel ${REDIS_LOGLEVEL:-warning}"
            - "--databases 2"
            - "--save 900 1"
            - "--save 300 10"
            - "--save 60 10000"
        volumes:
            - ./redis/data:/data
        networks:
          - mongodb_net
    mongodb:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - ./mongo/data:/data/db
        networks:
          - mongodb_net
```

EDITED: my web server send css files like text\plain, i include mime.types but its not resolve problem

Comment: Try `COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` instead.

Comment: @super i fixed my problem. But i dont know what i do)